# Applicative is to monad what X is to comonad

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, comonad

Can we solve this equation for X ?

> Applicative is to monad what X is to comonad

Comment: `ComonadApply is to Comonad like Applicative is to Monad.`  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.7.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:ComonadApply It doesn't seem to be very different from Applicative...

Comment: sounds like an answer !

Comment: @danidiaz I see that a `ComonadApply` must be a `Comonad` -- unlike `Applicative`s which do not have to be `Monad`s. This looks as a main difference to me.

Comment: @chi: `ComonadApply` looks like `Apply` (`Applicative` without `pure`). It also looks like it can be implemented without any `Comonad` specific terms. The main difference to `Applicative` is the documentation of the `extract`/`duplicate` + `<*>` laws (and of course `pure`; see PureScript's typeclass hierarchy for an example of `Apply f => Applicative f`).

Comment: @chi: So, the superclass implication arrow `Applicative a => Monad a` *also* is reversed? ;-P

Comment: @yatima2975 Well, adding "co-" shouldn't reverse _all_ arrows... ;)

Comment: adding co- should reverse all arrows in the category that the typeclass represents. Although that only really helps when there's an identity arrow - without the identity arrow we don't have a category so then it's harder to think about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After giving it some thought, I think this is actually a backward question. One might think that [`ComonadApply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.7.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:ComonadApply) is to `Comonad` what `Applicative` is to `Monad`, but that is not the case. But to see this, let us use PureScript's typeclass hierarchy:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Apply f where
    apply :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b -- (<*>)

class Apply f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a

class Applicative m => Monad m where
    bind :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b  -- (>>=)
 -- join :: m (m a) -> m a
 -- join = flip bind id
```

As you can see, `ComonadApply` is merely `(Apply w, Comonad w) => w`. However, `Applicative`'s ability to inject values into the functor with `pure` is the real difference.

The definition of a `Comonad` as the categorical dual consists of `return`'s dual `extract` and `bind`'s dual `extend` (or the alternative definiton via `duplicate` as `join`'s dual):

```
class Functor w => Comonad w where
    extract   :: w a -> a        
    extend    :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
 -- extend f  = fmap f . duplicate k
 -- duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)
 -- duplicate = extend id
```

So if we look at the step from `Applicative` to `Monad`, the logical step between would be a typeclass with `pure`'s dual:

```
class Apply w => Extract w where
    extract :: w a -> a

class Extract w => Comonad w where
    extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
```

Note that we cannot define `extract` in terms of `extend` or `duplicate`, and neither can we define `pure`/`return` in terms of `bind` or `join`, so this seems like the "logical" step. `apply` is mostly irrelevant here; it can be defined for either `Extract` or `Monad`, as long as their laws hold:

```
applyC f = fmap $ extract f   -- Comonad variant; needs only Extract actually (*)
applyM f = bind f . flip fmap -- Monad variant; we need join or bind
```

So `Extract` (getting values out) is to `Comonad`  what `Applicative` (getting values in) is to `Monad`. `Apply` is more or less a happy little accident along the way. It would be interesting whether there are types in Hask that have `Extract`, but not `Comonad` (or `Extend` but not `Comonad`, see below), but I guess those are rather rare.

Note that `Extract` doesn't exist—yet. But neither did `Applicative` in the [2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/). Also, any type that is both an instance of `Extract` and `Applicative` automatically is both a `Monad` and a `Comonad`, since you can define `bind` and `extend` in terms of `extract` and `pure`:

```
bindC :: Extract w => w a -> (a -> w b) -> w b
bindC k f = f $ extract k

extendM :: Applicative w => (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
extendM f k = pure $ f k
```

<sub>* Being able to define `apply` in terms of `extract` is a sign that `class Extend w => Comonad w` could be more feasible, but one could have split `Monad` into `class (Applicative f, Bind f) => Monad f` and therefore `Comonad` into `(Extend w, Extract w) => Comonad w`, so it's more or less splitting hair.</sub>

Comment: No, not Extract... [Extractive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extractive)!

Comment: ComonadApply w isn't (Apply w, Comonad w). ComonadApply requires zippiness (not growing a structure, rather than Apply's act of growing a structure). For example, the ComonadApply instance for [a] is different to the Apply instance for [a] - it's closer to that of ZipList.

Comment: Of course I mean to use NonEmpty as an example rather than []

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that `Apply` class should not be a part of the picture at all.

For example the definition of `apply` in @Zeta's answer does not seem to be well-behaved. In particular, it always discards the context of the first argument and only uses the context of the second argument.

Intuitively, it seems that comonad is about "splitting" the context instead of combining, and so "co-applicative" should be the same.

This question seems to have better answers: [Is there a concept of something like co-applicative functors sitting between comonads and functors?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/is-there-a-concept-of-something-like-co-applicative-functors-sitting-between-com).